# get the data from user input fields

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to get the data from user input fields - width and hieght:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="add_item_id" name="add_order_items" class="wc-product-search" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-multiple="true" />
    <input name="wpti_x" placeholder="Width" class="wpti-product-size" id="wpti-product-x" type="number">
    <input name="wpti_y" placeholder="Height" class="wpti-product-size" id="wpti-product-y" type="number">
</form>
```

I need to pass it (using javascript/jquery via POST) to this `minified` JS:

```
add_item:function(d){if(d=d.split(",")){var e=d.length;c.block(),a.each(d,function(d,f){var g={action:"woocommerce_add_order_item",item_to_add:f,order_id:woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes.post_id,security:woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes.order_item_nonce,width:1200,height:1200};
```

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: Did you try $('#wpti-product-x').val() instead of using a constant 1200 for width and $('#wpti-product-y').val() for height. With .val() you will get the value of the input. You can then use the parseInt(  ) method just to make sure you're getting a number.

Comment: It actually uses the minified file, and i get an uncaught type error when adding $(#wpti-product-x).val() for these values. Will add the minified function above

Comment: @MuhamadMuzahirKhodabucus  thank you, I have managed to get it to work with this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you use  `$('#wpti-product-x').val()`  and  `$('#wpti-product-x').val()`  this will work for you.

You may need to edit the unminified version and then minify it again.